# What are the uses of jquery ui ? and why not use jquery instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What are the uses of jquery ui ? and why not use jquery instead ?

I've read about Jquery ui in their official site , however , I'm still confused as to what it can do for me and whether I should study it or not ? I'm an aspiring Website Designer.

Comment: jQuery UI is a library that provides common UI components (such as modal dialogs). It's built upon jQuery, so you would use both together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jQueryUI` comes with many components such as slider-bars, accordions and widgets that you won't find with `jQuery`. `jQuery` by itself is simply a Javascript abstraction, allowing you to write agile code for the client-side. `jQuery` is also a dependency for `jQueryUI`, so you will need it in order to use the latter library.

It's similar to `Twitter Bootstrap` in its feasibility.

Here are a few demos for you to look over to demonstrate the difference: http://jqueryui.com/demos/

Comment: @hopehelpedThank you for taking the time to answer my question. I'm still at the process of discovering the effects they can produce. If I may , may I just ask , can a slider function be achieved by jquery alone ? I mean slider like the one on this site : [http://www.togather.com/]

Answer (score 2):

You don't use one instead of the other.

jQuery UI is dependent on jQuery. jQuery UI offers widgets and effects you can use on your website.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery UI does not replace JQuery, it is an extension of it and relies on it. It provides a few widgets like progress bars or date pickers for instance.